# My regex correctly doesn't accept a string online, but preg_match() returns true

Tags: php, regex

I have this regular expression `/^(string@)([^#\s\\\\]|(\\\d{3}))*$/`.

It's supposed to accept strings that start with `string@`, then all characters but `#`, `\`, or any whitespace characters can follow. `\` can only appear when it's followed by 3 digits.

When I test this regex with the string `string@test\07test` on regex101.com and phpliveregex.com, no matches are found (correctly), but `preg_match()` returns `true` for the same string.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

```
$regex = "/^(string@)([^#\s\\\\]|(\\\d{3}))*$/";

preg_match($regex, 'string@test\07test'); # this returns false, as it should

preg_match($regex, "string@test\07test"); # this returns true
```

The test string is taken from a file using `fgets()` and stored in a variable, though, so I can't pass it to `preg_match()` and put apostrophes around it, I need to pass the variable ($string, for example), and `preg_match($regex, $string)` incorrectly returns true again.

Comment: I am absolutely noob on php so i might missed something, but for me it returns 0 (false).  http://www.writephponline.com/. `$res=preg_match('/^(string@)([^#s]|(d{3}))*$/', 'string@test7test', $matches); var_dump($matches); var_dump($res);`. Am I miss something?

Comment: It seems you're testing `string@test7test` instead of `string@test\07test`. Your answer made me realise something though. I'm going to update the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first:

`'\07'` is a string of length 3 beginning with a backslash character.

`"\07"` is a string of length 1 consisting of ASCII x'07'

```
Interactive shell

php > echo strlen('\07');
3
php > echo strlen("\07");
1
php >
```

[See PHP Strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Regex:

```
/^string@(?:[^#\s\\]|\\(?=\d{3}))*$/
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r4yz1C/2/)

1. `^` Matches start of string.
2. `string@` Matches string@.
3. `[^#\s\\]` Matches any character other than #, white space or \.
4. `|` or
5. `\\(?=\d{3})` Matches \ if followed by 3 digits.
6. `(?: expression 3 through 5)*` matched 0 or more times.
7. `$` Matches the end of string.

Code:

```
<?php
$tests = [
    'abcd',
    'string@ test',
    'string@#test',
    'string@\07test',
    'string@\075test',
    'string@test'
];

$regex = '/^string@(?:[^#\s\\\\]|\\\\(?=\d{3}))*$/';
foreach ($tests as $test) {
    if (preg_match($regex, $test)) {
        echo "$test\n";
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
string@\075test
string@test
```